# Compare dictionaries in a Python list and append results

Tags: python, dictionary, append, compare

I am trying to loop through an array of dictionaries, compare each value between them and then append the results inside the dictionary.

for example if we have the following array:

```
epidemics = [{"Disease": "B", "year": "1980"},
             {"Disease": "C", "year": "1975"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "1996"},
             {"Disease": "E", "year": "2000"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "2020"}]
```

if the an epidemic of the same disease occurred in other years as well, the outcome I am trying to achieve is:

```
 epidemics = [{"Disease": "B", "year": "1980", "occurredIn": ["1996", "2020"]},
             {"Disease": "C", "year": "1975"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "1996", "occurredIn": ["1980", "2020"]},
             {"Disease": "E", "year": "2000"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "2020", "occurredIn": ["1980", "1996"]}]
```

this is where I got so far:

```
for index, a in enumerate(epidemics):
  v_b = []

  for b in epidemics[index+1:]:
    if a['Disease'] == b['Disease']:
        v_b.append(b["year"])
        a['occurredIn'] = v_b
```

it prints me:

```
[{'Disease': 'B', 'year': '1980', 'occurredIn': ['1996', '2020']},
 {'Disease': 'C', 'year': '1975'},
 {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '1996', 'occurredIn': ['2020']},
 {'Disease': 'E', 'year': '2000'}, 
 {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '2020'}]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: if i may, i don't think the outcome you want is actually a good structure. why not just store Disease B *once*, with all years mentioned in the same place? If you need stuff on an year basis, you can always access that information accordingly. This structure would be a simple dict with the key as the Disease, and the values as a list of years

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Thanks for the tip....this data was just an example, the data that I am working with is much more robust. Anyway I will keep that in mind. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a temporary dictionary and build a set of years for each disease. Then using this dictionary reform the `epidemics` list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

epidemics = [{"Disease": "B", "year": "1980"},
             {"Disease": "C", "year": "1975"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "1996"},
             {"Disease": "E", "year": "2000"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "2020"}]

d = defaultdict(set)
for dd in epidemics:
    disease = dd['Disease']
    d[disease].add(dd['year'])

for i,dd in enumerate(epidemics):
    years = d[dd['Disease']]-set([dd['year']])
    if years:
        epidemics[i]['occurredIn'] = years

print(epidemics)
```

Output:

```
[{'Disease': 'B', 'year': '1980', 'occurredIn': {'2020', '1996'}},
 {'Disease': 'C', 'year': '1975'},
 {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '1996', 'occurredIn': {'1980', '2020'}},
 {'Disease': 'E', 'year': '2000'},
 {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '2020', 'occurredIn': {'1980', '1996'}}]
```

Comment: Switched to using `defaultdict` instead of `setdefault()` to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Helder'hp'Pinto No worries. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new dictionary based on the years the disease occurred, for example:

```py
epidemics = [{"Disease": "B", "year": "1980"},
             {"Disease": "C", "year": "1975"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "1996"},
             {"Disease": "E", "year": "2000"},
             {"Disease": "B", "year": "2020"}]

output = []
for ep in epidemics:
    other_years = set(
        other_ep['year'] for other_ep in epidemics if (
            ep['Disease'] == other_ep['Disease'] and ep['year'] != other_ep['year']
            )
    )

    output.append(
        ep if not other_years else {**ep, 'occurredIn': list(other_years)}
    )

print(output)
>>> {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '1980', 'occurredIn': ['2020', '1996']}
>>> {'Disease': 'C', 'year': '1975'}
>>> {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '1996', 'occurredIn': ['1980', '2020']}
>>> {'Disease': 'E', 'year': '2000'}
>>> {'Disease': 'B', 'year': '2020', 'occurredIn': ['1980', '1996']}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Marcos